# Unity 2D - Jump Animation Reset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm new to the Unity world (2D) and I've run into some problems.

I have a script in which i want to jump. When i jump, the jump animation is super fast. You can only see it in the animator.

I have two other animations (Idle, Run) that work without any problems.

Can you please help me? :(

```
    public class Player : MonoBehaviour

{
    private Rigidbody2D rigid;

    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpForce = 5.0f;
    private bool resetJump;
    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 5.0f;
    private PlayerAnimation playerAnim;
    private SpriteRenderer playerSprite;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        ...
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Movement();
    }

    void Movement()
    {
        float move = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        Flip(move);

        if (IsGrounded())
        {            
            playerAnim.Jump(false);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && IsGrounded() == true)
        {
            rigid.velocity = new Vector2(rigid.velocity.x, jumpForce);            
            StartCoroutine(ResetJumpNeededRoutine());
            playerAnim.Jump(true);
        }        
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, rigid.velocity.y);
        playerAnim.Move(move);
    }

    void Flip(float move)
    {
        ...
    }

    bool IsGrounded()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, 0.3f, 1 << 8);
        if (hitInfo.collider != null)
        {
            if (resetJump == false)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    IEnumerator ResetJumpNeededRoutine()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        resetJump = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to look into the animator and animation before looking at the script. Check if: a) The animator speed (1 is default) b) There is a "Has Exit Time" on the animator state, You could try to uncheck it and it would way for the animation to end before changing states. c) Use a trigger instead of a boolean for the animation (set the default to be idle and trigger the animation when you jump). It seems there is nothing wrong with your code so I imagine it's something related to animator or the animation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have checked the points you mentioned again.
a. Speed = 1; I have changed and tested, no change
b. Has Exit Time = disabled, I also tried with and without, no change
c. Changed to trigger; no change

Can you think of any other options? Can I upload information that makes error analysis easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in ur code just after space is pressed the resetjump is getting false and isGrounded() is returning true and hence jump anim is getting false. So what i insist is to set trigger instead of setting playerAnim.jump use playerAnim.SetTrigger("Jump").

Study about animation trigger we use trigger to play animations like shoot and jump as these animation are true and then at next instant false.

Comment: Did it worked 4 u. Just curious about did it solved ur issue or not. THANK YOU

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I now have a trigger for jumping and a trigger for running. It works fine.